# Output file missing

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2013

I have a project in my solution upon which many others depend, `DataMonitor.Common`. One of my very few build errors is :

```
Error   6   Metadata file 'C:\Development\DataMonSol\DataMonitor.Common\bin\Release\DataMonitor.Common.dll' could not be found  C:\Development\DataMonSol\DataMonitor.Database\CSC  DataMonitor.Database
```

Yet there are no build errors with `DataMonitor.Common`; its output directory is set to the standard `bin\Debug\`. The only apparent factor is that `DataMonitor.Common.dll` is not found anywhere at all. What could this be? I rewrote this whole project from VB.NET to C# last night to escape all the hidden little tricks VS plays with a VB.NET project, and now I get this. What could cause this?

**JUST IN:**

I am recreating the solution in a new solution, and in this one, the projects are building. Something behind the scenes is really fubar in the older solution.

**THIS IS THE BUILD WINDOW OUTPUT (Excuse the verbosity):**

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: DataMonitor.Data,
>   Configuration: Release Any CPU ------ 1>  DataMonitor.Data ->
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\DataMonitor.Data\bin\Release\DataMonitor.Data.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\sqlceca40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\sqlcecompact40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\sqlceer40EN.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\sqlceme40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\sqlceqp40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\sqlcese40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest 1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\README_ENU.txt
>   1>  9 File(s) copied 1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\sqlceca40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\sqlcecompact40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\sqlceer40EN.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\sqlceme40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\sqlceqp40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\sqlcese40.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll
>   1> 
>   C:\Development\DataMonSol\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\README_ENU.txt
>   1>  9 File(s) copied 2>------ Rebuild All started: Project:
>   DataMonitor.Database, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>   2>C:\Development\DataMonSol\DataMonitor.Database\DataMonitorDbContext.cs(11,33,11,45):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ImportConfig' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: DataMonitor.Logging,
>   Configuration: Release Any CPU ------ 3>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata
>   file
>   'C:\Development\DataMonSol\DataMonitor.Database\bin\Release\DataMonitor.Database.dll'
>   could not be found 4>------ Rebuild All started: Project:
>   DataMonitor.Common, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------ 4>CSC :
>   error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'C:\Development\DataMonSol\DataMonitor.Logging\bin\Release\DataMonitor.Logging.dll'
>   could not be found 5>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Mothership,
>   Configuration: Release Any CPU ------ 5>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "DataMonitor.Database". Check to make sure the assembly
>   exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may
>   get compilation errors. 5>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'C:\Development\DataMonSol\DataMonitor.Common\bin\Release\DataMonitor.Common.dll'
>   could not be found 5>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'C:\Development\DataMonSol\DataMonitor.Logging\bin\Release\DataMonitor.Logging.dll'
>   could not be found

Comment: You say that the debug version is in its Debug directory, but is the release version in the Release directory? That's the one that is referenced in your error message.

Comment: No, I do not say the debug version is in it's Debug directory. The Debug version is nowhere, just like the Release version, nowhere.

Comment: OK, and what does it say in the build output window? Is it the expected path?

Comment: The build window says nothing about building that project.

Comment: Check the Configuration section of your solution properties. Is the project checked for build?

Comment: All projects are checked for build. This is a strange and mysterious problem, not an everyday mistake.

Comment: As you don't give these details in your OP, one have to make assumptions. How can you say that "the build window says nothing about building that project" whereas you state that "there are no build errors with DataMonitor.Common" in your OP? No build errors and no build at all are different things. If it builds it, there *will* be some kind of output in the build messages.

Comment: @PatriceGahide Can you see anything in the build output about that file building? I didn't pollute the page with all that for poops and giggles.